# p:commandbutton on primefaces cannot be clicked twice

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

hello i was testing out the example given on the official primefaces website an i noticed that my `<p:commandButton>` does not work well in that once i click it to update a value, it stays highlighted and cannot be clicked again to update the value again. Here is the xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
      type="text/javascript"></script>

<h:head>

    </h:head>
    <h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" styleClass="ui-grid">
        <h:outputLabel for="basic" value="Basic Spinner: " />
        <p:spinner id="basic" value="#{spinnerView.number1}" />

        <h:outputLabel for="step" value="Step Factor: " />
        <p:spinner id="step" value="#{spinnerView.number2}"       stepFactor="0.25" />

        <h:outputLabel for="minMax" value="Min/Max: " />
        <p:spinner id="minMax" value="#{spinnerView.number3}" min="0" max="100" />

        <h:outputLabel for="prefix" value="Prefix: " />
        <p:spinner id="prefix" value="#{spinnerView.number4}" prefix="$" min="0" />

        <h:outputLabel for="ajaxSpinner" value="Ajax Spinner: " />
        <p:outputPanel>
            <p:spinner id="ajaxSpinner" value="#{spinnerView.number5}">
                <p:ajax update="ajaxSpinnerValue" process="@this" />
            </p:spinner>
            <h:outputText id="ajaxSpinnerValue" value="#{spinnerView.number5}" style="padding-left: 10px" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display"  oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" />

    <p:dialog header="Values" widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fold" hideEffect="fold">
        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            <h:outputText value="Value 1: " />
            <h:outputText value="#{spinnerView.number1}" />

            <h:outputText value="Value 2: " />
            <h:outputText value="#{spinnerView.number2}" />

            <h:outputText value="Value 3: " />
            <h:outputText value="#{spinnerView.number3}" />

            <h:outputText value="Value 4: " />
            <h:outputText value="#{spinnerView.number4}" />

            <h:outputText value="Value 5: " />
            <h:outputText value="#{spinnerView.number5}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
</html>
```

And this is the managed bean:

```
package uk.soton.lostatnight;


import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class SpinnerView {

private int number1;   
private double number2;  
private int number3;   
private int number4; 
private int number5;

public int getNumber1() {
    return number1;
}

public void setNumber1(int number1) {
    this.number1 = number1;
}

public double getNumber2() {
    return number2;
}

public void setNumber2(double number2) {
    this.number2 = number2;
}

public int getNumber3() {
    return number3;
}

public void setNumber3(int number3) {
    this.number3 = number3;
}

public int getNumber4() {
    return number4;
}

public void setNumber4(int number4) {
    this.number4 = number4;
}

public int getNumber5() {
    return number5;
}

public void setNumber5(int number5) {
    this.number5 = number5;
}
}
```

I find this weird so does anyone have any solutions to this problem or is it the cause of something else like the web or pom.xml files and if so how can i fix this?

Comment: did you try the ajax  doubleclick  evet ?!?

Comment: you could try making it a p:commandLink and style it like a button

Comment: You need a h:body